# Display a name from a specific id to the nav bar page in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

(New Image)The objective is to display the name labels in the side navbar, and you can edit that name from a table in the database. This is when I don't want that name labels I can change it to label or something like that, and I am using EF. If you have any questions feel free to ask, I will gladly answer.

I have tried `@html.display` name with foreach model but it's not working

I tried almost everything and the results were the same:

> Object as an instance of an object

or something like that.

Comment: **(1)** screenshot is just a black box - no content. **(2)** Please **show us some code** here, in your question - not just as  a screenshot! What exactly are you trying to do? Still very unclear ....

Comment: ok give me a secont

Comment: @marc_s i hope i provide enough thing sense i can´t really post something about the code